# white space coming in place of scroll bar while filtering and long text is coming with

Tags: ng-grid

Here is the plunker created http://plnkr.co/edit/5DhDmI1Odhrys4jYDwIB?p=preview

I have associated textbox with ng-grid filter.

```
$scope.filterOptions = {
    filterText:''
  }
  $scope.$watch('filterText',function(){
  $scope.filterOptions.filterText=$scope.filterText;
  });
```

1. If you enter "moroni" in the text box, only one row in grid will be displayed. But at the right, white space is visible. Is there a way to fix it.
2. First row in the plunker example is having very big string, When text is very long, only part of it is displayed. Is it possible to break the string and display it in multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the **text not wrapping** issue by setting the rowHeight in gridoptions to value that fits your longest string:

```
rowHeight:50
```

And add this definition to your css:

```
.ngCellText {
    white-space: unset;
}
```

The **width whitespace** issue is clearly a bug in ng-grid. This grid is not really a table but a lot of positioned and measured divs that look like a table. Seems the developers forgot to add some extra width to the row when no scrollbar is visible. You can only overcome this if you patch the code (not recommended) or setting the gridheight to a value in which all rows can be displayed without scrollbars.

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 500px; 
    height: 300px
}
```

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mo7ceFtO7M7885vPQSzf?p=preview).

Anyhow, since these are mere unpractical hacks, I suggest you have a look at table based directive like [trNgGrid](http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/) which has all the features of ng-grid but is way more flexible when it comes to dynamic row heights.